# Create new base class object from derived class object in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, types, type-conversion

I've got an object of type `Derived` but want to have one of type `Base`. Normally, I can simply cast the object to a reference of `Base`. However, for my WCF service, I really want to expose the `Base` class only.

Is there a neat way to get the `Base` to a `Derived` object (or create a new `Base` from the `Derived` object) where the dynamic type is `Base`?

Example:

```
myWcfResult.PropertyOfTypeBase = objectOfTypeDerived; // do some magic in this line
Assert.Trace(myWcfResult.PropertyOfTypeBase.GetType() == typeof(Base)); // should hold afterwards
// or at least WCF should be able to serialize it correctly into an XML element of type Base
```

Comment: Can you add a small code sample to clarify the situation? If you never want to give the user the opportunity to cast `Base` to `Derived` then I think creating a new `Base` with the `Derived`'s properties is a good solution.

Comment: Could you add an example? I didn't really understand.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing else comes up I'm going to accept my own hackaround as solution: using AutoMapper to clone the `Derived` into a new `Base`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Base,Base>();
Mapper.Map<Base,Base>(objectOfTypeDerived);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is to hide the extra properties of the `Derived` class, then   there are two options

1. Either the consumer allows you to specify the type explicitly
2. Or you have to change your design.

In the second case you should consider using composition instead of inheritance e.g.

- Wrap the `Base` or `Derived` objects into a new adapter class that will only expose the required properties
- Have the Base class as it is, but instead of adding the extra functionality by deriving from it, use composition: the Base class would contain another object that would define some aspects of the behaviour.

It is difficult to help you without a concrete example I am afraid.

Comment: (1) as I said, the consumer is WCF. I don't know if it is possible to specify the type explicitly. (2) I don't really want to do that: adding a new adapter class leads me to write an adapter for hundreds of properties, composition leads to an awful WSDL contract.

Comment: @D.R., I am afraid you need to be a lot more detailed. I am certainly not an expert in WCF, but last time I used it I had to set attributes on every property I wanted serialized?